# 04 Honda pilot only reading 11.2v on OBD, alternator is brand new, battery replaced in August

Tags: honda, voltage, pilot

So...my wife's 04 pilot battery light came on, it had come on intermittently over the past months but never stayed on until today. Hooked up my OBD, 11.2v. Damn, so i replaced the alternator, which was a pain (I hate engineers). $200 and 3 hours later, still the same issue. Voltage fluctuates between 11.0-11.5 depending on the load, reving to 2500, lights, a/c, doesn't go under 11 but not over 11.5...bad ground or short somewhere I imagine..thoughts, recommendations? Side note, cruise control went out a few months ago when the brake pedal sensor little rubber stop broke/fell out, fixed the pedal issue, but still no CC...don't think they're related, but who knows.
Thanks in advance,
Bill

Comment: Examine battery cable connections for corrosion, preventing electrical connections. Examine battery grounds, battery to chassis and chassis to engine block for corrosion. Main power connections checked, is the drive belt tight, not allowing belt slippage? As a rule, alternators usually output around 14.5vdc, approximately 2.5 volts higher than battery voltage, to supply all the electrical needs of a vehicle while recharging the battery after every startup. Fix the problem of main power before guessing on other possible electrical/electronic problems.

Comment: Thanks! That was my next move.

Comment: Yeah, I'm an idiot... the belt got slung off cuz it was probably only half way on the bottom pulley where I couldn't see... yeah I know

Comment: No one's perfect or an expert. The important part is the solution to the problem no matter who solves it.

Comment: Absolutely. It happens